# Prove that $(ax + by + cz)^2 \leq (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that for any real number $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$ and $z$, there results
$(ax + by + cz)^2 \leq (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$

I have thought this Q for long time but I still can't get the answer.
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you!~

Comment: See [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality)

Comment: Another proof is elementary: consider $f(t)=(a^2+b^2+c^2)t^2-2(ax+by+cz)t+(x^2+y^2+z^2)=(at-x)^2+(bt-y)^2+(ct-z)^2\ge0$ whenever $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Another proof is about [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Comment: @FrankScience: that's basically the same idea as the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{RHS}&=&(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)+(a^2y^2+b^2x^2)+(a^2z^2+c^2x^2)+(+b^2z^2+c^2y^2)\\
&=&(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2+2axby+2bycz+2czax)+(a^2y^2+b^2x^2-2aybx)+(a^2z^2+c^2x^2-2azcx)+(b^2z^2+c^2y^2-2bzcy)\\
&=&(ax+by+cz)^2+(ay-bx)^2+(az-cx)^2+(bz-cy)^2\\
&\geq&(ax+by+cz)^2\\
&\geq&\text{LHS}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

This question is direct application of [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(a,b,c)$ and $v=(x,y,z)$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We have
$$
(\left<u,v\right>)^2=(ax+by+cz)^2 \text{ and } \|u\|^2\|v\|^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).
$$
Since $(\left<u,v\right>)^2\leq \|u\|^2\|v\|^2$ we have the given inequality.